# playframework: Request.current in Job

Tags: java, playframework, httprequest, jobs

I use playframework, and I am struggling with a concurrent task:

I have a module in which methods use `Request.current` (module FbGraph). I need to access these methods from `Job`, but `Job` runs on another thread. In this thread, `Request.current` returns `null`, and because of this, the module does not work.

Can I pass the value of the current request to `Job`? Will `Request.current` return the same value as in the main thread? Or do I need to fix something in the module, and keep the current request value within it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly pass the request object to your Job class. Suppose you have the following job class:

```
public class MyJob extends Job<Object> {
   private Request request;
   public MyJob() {
      request = Request.current();
   }
   public void doJob() {
      // here you use the request object
   }
}
```

And use your MyJob:

```
public static void myAction() {
   ...
   new MyJob().now();
   ...
}
```

For other modules that use Request.current() you will need to either check if you can pass request object to that module, or use that module in your controller action thread.

Comment: Thanks. So, need to fix module.